# How to make Required on Upload Image Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

i want to make require for image upload button
this is the code on my view

Modal

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Unggah Gambar</h4>
  </div>

  <form id="upload-image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input id="input-dim-1" name="inputdim1[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading" accept="image/*">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Keluar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
$("#input-dim-1").fileinput({
      uploadExtraData: {_token:"{{csrf_token()}}", key : key},
      uploadUrl: "{!! route('admin.product.getupload') !!}",
      allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg"],
      minImageWidth: 50,
      minImageHeight: 50,
      maxFileCount: 5
    });
```

Ajax

```
$('#form-product').submit(function(event) {
     if ($("#input-dim-1").val() == '') {
       event.preventDefault();
       alert("Image Is Required");
     } else {
       form.submit();
       }
       return false;
     });
```

Now the required is appears when user not uploaded image, but this appear too when user have uploaded image :(
can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `required` tag you can set on the input?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes i have, but not working

Comment: If you have `required` on your input then try change the type of your button to `type="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
<input id="input-dim-1" name="inputdim1[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading" accept="image/*">
```

Backend side when using laravel you could validate the array input to be required like so:

```
'inputdim1.*' => 'required'
```

Html side you could add required attribute:

```
<input id="input-dim-1" name="inputdim1[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading" accept="image/*" required>
```